# How to get Client Context in SharePoint 2013 Provider Hosted APP

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

I am created 1 Provider Hosted App in SharePoint 2013. I am not able to get Client Context.

I have tried different options for getting the Client context. Almost all option that is available to get client context but no success.

FYI :- I host this app on my local iis, and without https

Please help me in this!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It depends where you need the ClientContext and if you need to access resources in host web or app web.

**Getting ClientContext on page**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SharePointContext spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(Context);
    using (ClientContext cc = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
    {
    }
}
```

**Getting ClientContext in remote event receiver**

```
public SPRemoteEventResult ProcessEvent(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
{
    using (ClientContext cc = TokenHelper.CreateAppEventClientContext(properties))
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I want on host web. The above code snippet I have used this also. But "spContext" is null.